# Better way to write this if condition with a force-unwrap?

Tags: swift

Given these variables:

```
let urls: [URL] = []    
let defaultURL = urls.first?
```

It's straightforward to write a conditional statement to do something based on whether there's a file or not.

```
if let url = defaultURL, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

But if you don't need to do something in the first case, I can't come up with a better way to write the condition than this:

```
if defaultURL == nil || !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: defaultURL!.path) {
    // Do something
}
```

Is there a better way to write this? I don't like the force-unwrap, but at the same time, it feels safe to write that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this situation.

The simplest one is to extract the condition into a separate function/closure and check

```
func fileExists(defaultUrl: URL?) -> Bool {
    guard let defaultUrl = defaultUrl else { return false }
    return FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: defaultUrl.path)
 }
```

The same can be done using a variable:

```
let fileExists: Bool

if let defaultUrl = defaultUrl {
   fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: defaultUrl.path)
} else {
   fileExists = false
}
```

Or, you can use `Optional.map`:

```
let fileExists = defaultUrl.map { FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: $0.path) } ?? false
```

Comment: I discarded the separate function because it feels like a lot for such a simple thing. I didn't think to use map, I like that thanks.

Comment: If you run `map` on `path`, instead, you don't need to define your own closure. You can also compare against true instead of nil-coalescing with `false`:  `(defaultURL?.path).map(FileManager.default.fileExists) == true`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more clear and readable by making a variable that makes if condition an english sentence  i.e.

```
let fileNotExists = !(defaultUrl.map{ FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: $0.path)} ?? false)
if fileNotExists {
    //Do your stuff
}
```